# Meteor swarm and mechanics confusion for its effects

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Meteor swarm is a very powerful spell. So that is why I'd like to know specifically how its mechanics are supposed to work.

The spell meteor swarm states

> Blazing orbs of fire plummet to the ground at **four different points** you can see within range. Each creature in a 40-foot-radius sphere centered on each point you choose must make a Dexterity saving throw. (emphasis mine)

It specifies different so I understand I may not choose the same point. However, it does not specify how far it has to be. Therefore, can it be 4 different points right next to each other or do they have to be 80 feet apart considering if each meteor must be at least its diameter's size apart?

It also specifies that

> A creature takes 20d6 fire damage and 20d6 bludgeoning damage on a failed save, or half as much damage on a successful one. A creature in the area of more than **one fiery burst** is affected only once. (emphasis mine)

Which means a single creature can only take a maximum of 20d6 fire damage. However, it states fiery burst so does that mean a creature can still take more than 20d6 bludgeoning damage?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The points may be anywhere within range, including inside the effect of each other, otherwise the second quoted part would be unnecessary.

The fiery burst refers to the whole effect. The phrase at the end of that quote, "affected only once," means affected by the spell. If it only meant the fire part, it would clearly say so.

Answer (score 1):

It is actually a very simple spell: to create the area of effect you draw four 40' radius spheres each centred on a point within 1 mile of the caster. They may overlap and the effect spreads around corners. Each creature within this area of effect takes 20d6 fire and 20d6 bludgeoning damage on a failed save, half that on a success.

Meteor Swarm PHB p.259

> Range: 1 mile
>
> Blazing orbs of fire plummet to the ground at four different points you can see within range. Each creature in a 40-foot-radius sphere centered on each point you choose must make a Dexterity saving throw. The sphere spreads around corners. A creature takes 20d6 fire damage and 20d6 bludgeoning damage on a failed
> save, or half as much damage on a successful one. A creature in the area of more than one fiery burst is affected only once.